# Soft-delete package location

Tags: java, spring, soft-delete

I have the existing spring project with following structure

```
-com.project
 -chat
   -domain
     -Chat
     -ChatRepository
     -ChatRepositoryImpl
     -...
   -exception
   -...
 -email
   -domain
     -Email
     -EmailRepository
     -EmailRepositoryImpl
     -...
 -...
```

I suppose that the project has this structure because after completing MVP it might be divided into microservices.

I want to add soft delete functionality for the Email by editing Email entity and modifying it's repository. But probably soft delete functionality in future will be needed for other entities too so now I am curious what to do.

Is it better to create some basic entity with isDeleted and deletedAt fields and basic SoftDeleteRepository in separate package and then all entities and repos will extend them or create some sort of a library which I will use in each package or maybe there are other ways to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say not to think so much about it unless if you're sure it'll be divided into microservices.

Even if you split them into different domains now you'll still need to refactor if `Email` for whatever reason calls `Chat`. This is something that can be a little tricky to avoid and will require refactoring anyway.

Just stick with having a `utility/common` folder that houses `SoftDeleteRepository` for now. You might need to refactor this into a separate artifact shared by both microservices or just copy/paste them. Sometimes it's good remember that a microservice are meant to be owned by different team and have different database. It's sometimes okay to copy paste =]